# Xcode auto layout constraints - why defaulting to negative padding?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am simply adding a UIView into the main view of a view controller. I want the height to always be 64px, but the width to stretch to the width of the screen.

However, when I go to add constraints, the left and right padding default to -16, even though the view is stretched all the way across its parent view. Even if I set these back to 0, when I run the app the -16 padding is added back in. What is going on here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just add Leading space to constrainer & Tailing space to constrainer in UIView with the boarder of UIViewController

Comment: I did that. But I can see the reason behind this padding. Would you please enlighten me. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Uncheck *"Constrain to margins" checkbox* in the pin menu (the first image in the question) while adding *spacing to nearest neighbor* for the new constraints.